# SP WebPart Jquery reference

Tags: web-part, jquery

Has anyone a reference to Jquery file in Visual web part to show. I need to se how it looks like.
Mine looks lke this :

```
 <script src="c:\users\wss_setup\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\VisualWebPartProjectreftest\VisualWebPartProjectreftest\VisualWebPart1\scripts\bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

but there must be a better way.
Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your scripts in a SharePoint Mapped folder.

[image]

Then give the reference like

```
<script src="../../../_layouts/Your Mapped Folder Name/js/rss.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Or upload your scripts into a document library, then refer it in your web part

```
<script src="/library name/rss.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: When I choose SharePoint Mapped folder, which map should I choose then? or should I create one?

Comment: You can choose existing one or create one?

Comment: Thx! I have fixed it.